# Hide python processes and threads output on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, output, python-multithreading

I have a Windows CMD that runs a python process. That process at the same time runs more processes using python multiprocessing, and threads.

All the prints output of that processes goes to the same CMD window. It's any way to hide all the processes output ?

I tried to do it using the next CMD command but it doesn't hide the output.

```
start "time_tester" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k C:\Python26\python.exe time_test.py > nul
```

Comment: I'm using ghostscript module, and my problem is to hide the module output, not mine prints. 

I'm trying also to put : 
        f = open('nul', 'w')
        sys.stdout = f   
on ghostscript module.. but no way

Comment: You may want to use subprocess

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding /b to CMD command and redirect the output to nul (> nul) solves my problem. In this way, all the processes and child processes return the output to the same CMD and now we can redirect it to nul.

```
start /b "Name" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k C:\Python26\python.exe script.py > nul
```